# Problems with Java on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I only have a Raspberry Pi to practice, and Visual Studio Code runs smoothly on it for many languages I've tried, but I can't seem to run Java on it. I installed the Extension Pack for Java, but when I create a Java Project and try to run it, the Debugger keeps loading and doesn't start at all. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Extension Pack and the Debugger, but without success. I know the solution might be obvious, but I tried googling it and found nothing.

Comment: You have to install a JDK package on your pc additionally.

Comment: after running "java -version" on terminal, I have this JDK installed -->  

openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Raspbian-2deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Raspbian-2deb10u1, mixed mode)

Comment: So then for understanding to issue: can you create a simple helloworld application and save the file as: hello.java
Then go the path of this file through terminal and type in terminal: javac hello.java  Then in terminal call class as: java hello  And follow the result

Comment: javac hello.java created a file named "hello.class", then when calling the class with "java hello" the error showed was ---> it wasn't possible to locate nor load the main class hello caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello

Comment: You can call as: java hello.class

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial/JavaHelloWorld.Project.mp4), can you get the result in Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the latest version of the extension "Language Support for Java by RedHat" wasn't working properly on my VSCode. I installed version 1.0.0 and it loaded everything and now I can run Java smoothly.